# High Speed LAN - Fibre vs CAT6

Tags: networking

I know this has been asked a couple of times before, but I need some tailored advice based on my situation.

I own a small estate in the UK, ex-farm sort of place, which several businesses now run from. We're in the process of upgrading our networking, placing an emphases on speed thanks to a media company now occupying one of our rentable office buildings.

My problem: I need transfer speeds between buildings of at least 1 gigabit (preferably more) - we have underground ducts that go to every building from our 'central hub', but all are over 100m (the average distance would be around 150m). We we need a high speed cable network for large size file sharing etc etc.

My question: Cat 6 is obviously limited to around 100m. Is it worth running fibre to switches that have SPF ports, or would it be best to run several Cat 6 lines, trunking several copper connections to get 2, 3, or up to 8 GB over the copper? If we're going down the fibre route, is it simply a media converter at the source end, and then an SPF switch client side? If the later, what hardware is needed?

Extra info: I can run as many copper lines as needed, including some redundant. There's not a whole load of clients that would feed off the speed, we just have two or three that need to read/write pretty quick.

Comment: I don’t quite understand: You say the cables would be too long for CAT6, so why even pursue CAT6? For fiber, you’d put a switch on either end, of course. The desired level of network protection (businesses from each other, core infrastructure, ...) is also quite important.

Comment: *"Cat 6 is obviously limited to around 100m"* -- You're confusing a type of cable with a protocol restriction.  There are other uses for Cat6 cable besides Ethernet.  FWIW the are various flavors of xDSL that cost much less than fibre or Ethernet over Cat6, the trade-off is speed.

Comment: Non-expert suggestion: fiber is going to be _much_ more future-proof, especially underground. Not to mention interference, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cat6 for 150m is a really bad idea. If your initial setup cost allows you to go for the fiber, you should definitely give that option the highest priority. A fiber would not only provide huge bandwidth, but also be totally upgradable if you ever need more speeds. The initial setup cost would be more, but it will probably be better in the long run. Also, you mention that currently, the load will not be huge, but considering that it may increase in the future, it would always be safe to stay with future-proof tech.